# курсор перебросить с одного поля на другое

Tags: c#, wpf

Как при нажатии <kbd>ENTER</kbd> перебросить курсор с одного поля на другое?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextBox Text="123" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" />
```

---

```
void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter) {
        var tr = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
        var fe = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
        if (fe != null)
            fe.MoveFocus(tr);
    }
}
```